# Tikz code: Cartesian space vs hough space

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I would like to write down using tikz the following graphs.

[image]

It would be great and extremely helpful if someone could post me the code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Yea I know :) The problem is that I am too lazy and I have no idea how to do it. :) I was hoping there were some geek that already done this or can help me out.

Comment: That's not the way the site works and. Even though some "geek" may occasionally roll up his/her sleeves and show off his/her TeX skills, this "do-the-work-for-me" attitude is not something that we want to encourage, because it would be detrimental to the site, in the long run. There are lots of TikZ examples on the site (also, see [this](http://www.texample.net)), some of which you could build on. Once you have a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), post it in your question; people are more likely to help you if you show you made some effort.

Comment: I suggest you make an attempt yourself first, and ask here if you have specific questions. Being lazy is not really the right basis for asking a question ;-)

Comment: I know. But it's really a pain, I think I'll simply copy the image. Well, at least I give it a try on asking this question :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JohnEntropy Nothing ventured, nothing gained :)